# Using Motorola EMDK in an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net-2.0, motorola-emdk

Is this possible?  We have WinForms (CF) apps which use the EMDK, and would like to do the same in an ASP.NET app.  All of the code samples provided with the EMDK distro are WinForms.  I assume you'd need some sort of ActiveX wrapper around the EMDK assemblies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to wrap anything you can use the scanner by Javascript.

They provide some samples using scanner with Javascript for the use of Pocket Browser, you can combine the provided Javascript with asp.net to start the scanner and __doPostBack to the server.

Download samples and pocket browser from: http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=12548

Comment: Thanks, I think we will have to pursue this.  We were hoping to find a free option (this isn't), but other alternatives have not presented...